# Omit images from webpage requested through HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I fetch webpages in order to feed data to my application. However, the pages contain a lot of images which I don't require at all. I only need the text data.
My problem is that the web requests take an unacceptable amount of time. I think the images also are fetch during a web request. Is there any way to eliminate the images and download only the text data?

The following is the code that I am using currently.

```
        var httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        httpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
        httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        httpWebRequest.Proxy = null;
        httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/html";

        string responseString = null;
        var httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        using (var responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                responseString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

Also, any other optimization suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: `Is there any way to eliminate the images and download only the text data?` you already download only the pure html not the images.

Comment: @L.B - OK. So is there no room for further optimization?

Comment: Optimization for speed, code?. For ex, If you used `WebClient`, you could have written your code in two lines. (of course WebClient is somehow subset of HttpWebRequest in terms of functionality)

Comment: @L.B - Oh, yeah! I got to know about WebClient just an hour ago, and reading about it. I will replace this existing code with WebClient one, as I don't seem to use the extra controlling features that HttpWebRequest provides. What I was asking was speed optimization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is incorrect.
`HttpWebRequest` does not know anything about HTML or images; it just sends raw HTTP requests.

You can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Do you mean that the images will be fetched no matter what I do? I mean my code might be wrong, but is there any way to fetch only the text, and not fetch the images?

Comment: +1. @MrBhoot, only HTML will be fetched. But it may contain images inlined with "data:" protocol or HTML could be slow/large for any other reason.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I see. It seems I will have to fire up Fiddler to examine the fetched data. Thanks, anyways.

Comment: @MrBhoot, images, css files, js files, etc. are referenced in html by links to separate resources (src=..., etc). Behind the scenes, a browser will read an html file and as it encounters links to images, it will issue separate requests for those. Unless you are issuing separate requests to download images as you encounter <img src="">, then WebRequest is just pulling down the text of the requested url.

Comment: @JayWalker - Alright. I got the point. I could also see that happening in Fiddler, from which I issued a web request. The images (and other files) were fetched through separate requests. I guess I will have to go back one step and do some reading. Thanks, anyways.

Comment: Firebug (https://getfirebug.com/downloads) is another tool like fiddler. it has a nice interface that shows request duration (timeline). this can help you determine if bandwidth/delay on the sender is a problem.

Comment: @JayWalker: But it's useless for non-browser requests.